# control radio button using checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, openlayers-3

I want to control radio buttons using checkbox.I have one checkbox as parent and four radio buttons as child.If i clicked on checkbox then dynamically check 4th radio button along with display layer,also i can check another radio buttons with display layers and if i unchecked the checkbox then uncheck radio button which is checked,disable layers.This works like layer switcher in open layers 3.

I have done little bit code but after i checked checkbox then dynamically 4th radio button with layer is display,remaining radio button cannot switch to other radio buttons and layers.

```
$('#builtup input').change(function () {
    var layer = $(this).val();//all radiobuttons value
    var cRad = $("#ck");//checkbox id
    builtup.forEach(function (e) { //builtup array contains four layers builtup[1975,1990,2000,2014]
        var n = e.get('name');
        if (cRad.is(':checked')) {
            if (n == 2014) //fourth radio button value=2014
            {
                $('#bb4').attr('checked', true); //fourth radio button is checked
                e.setVisible(n == 2014);  //visible fourth layer
            }
            if (n == layer) //for switching between othe radio
            {

                $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', true);
                e.setVisible(n == layer);

            }
        }
        else  //uncheck all radio and disable layers
        {
            $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
            e.setVisible(false);
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="builtup" class="list-unstyled"> <li><input type="checkbox" id="ck" name="layer1" value="chk">Built-up Area</li> <li><input type="radio" id="bb1" name="layer1" value="1975">1975</li> <li><input type="radio" id="bb2" name="layer1" value="1990">1990</li> <li><input type="radio" id="bb3" name="layer1" value="2000">2000</li> <li><input type="radio" id="bb4" name="layer1" value="2014">2014</li></ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your code for the HTML?

Comment: <ul id="builtup" class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><input type="checkbox" id="ck" name="layer1" value="chk">Built-up Area</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" id="bb1" name="layer1" value="1975">1975</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" id="bb2" name="layer1" value="1990">1990</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" id="bb3" name="layer1" value="2000">2000</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" id="bb4" name="layer1" value="2014">2014</li></ul>